# How to enable hibernation after certain sleep duration automatically in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, laptop, sleep, hibernate, power-management

I had an old hp laptop that used to go to hibernate after certain hours of sleep duration. So for eg., if I sleep my laptop manually it would automatically goes to hibernate after a certain hour or 1.

So in my new hp laptop, I'm seeking this same functionality where after sleeping for 1 hour or so, it should go to hibernate mode automatically resulting in battery saving.

<< Heads up information >>

1. I Already tried to copy power settings from the old laptop to the new one, but I couldn't replicate the same functionality.
2. using Windows 11
3. new HP laptop 15s-eq2144au

How do I solve my problem?

Comment: Did you go to *Advanced* Power Options for each plan?

Comment: yes, but same behavior